# Problems reading video device

Tags: linux, go

I'm trying to access the video device on my embedded system, and get the **error**: 
"dev/video0 not a V4L capture device".

I'm using this module to find devices: https://github.com/korandiz/v4l

**System**: 
Linux 4.9.39+linaro aarch64 
**Camera**(using terminal cmd: v4l2-ctl --list-devices): 
Qualcomm Camera Subsystem (platform:1b0ac00.camss):
/dev/video0 ... /video3
Qualcomm Venus video decoder (platform:qcom-venus):
/dev/video4 ... /video5

I want to use https://github.com/gen2brain/cam2ip in my embedded system, which is using v4l.
My question is, *how do i access a qualcomm camera system in go?*

Comment: Are you using `/dev/video*` (with a wildcard), or `/dev/video3` (with an actual device name)? It's likely that this library requires a real path and not a wildcard pattern.

Comment: The source code of opening a device [is quite smple](https://github.com/korandiz/v4l/blob/29ee50f8332da69f6ab020af393c2242f5a5dc0e/device.go#L172). Why not try to implement "printf-style debugging" to get an idea which of the two places which return `ErrWrongDevice` is actually exercised in your case, and then think about the reasons? Also please note that `v4l2-ctl` may do some magic like loading special kernel modules which actually enable the devices, or somehow turn them on by sending them some `ioctl`s; does yout code work after running `v2l2-ctl`?